# How do I get the date (not time or any alphabetic characters) from this NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I have an `NSString` that prints:

> recent update Last Updated: 10/02/2014 03:22:PM

I want to get this date only `10/02/2014`. How will I go about doing this? Any suggestions or tips are appreciated. I am guessing I need to use `NSRange`, but I am not too sure.

```
NSString *recentUpdate = [defaults stringForKey:@"EGORefreshTableView_LastRefresh"];
```

Comment: Closely, closely related: [Finding date time in NSString using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10557035)

Comment: You write code to parse the string.  How fancy the code needs to be depends on any possible variations in the string structure.  At it's simplest you could just substring from char 24 for length 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the day and month will always be 2-digits, this is a quick solution:

```
[recentUpdate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(28, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple string parsing:

```
NSArray *stringParts = [recentUpdate componentsSeparatedBy:@" "];
NSString *datePortion = stringParts[4];
```

Do proper error checking incase the string doesn't have the right number of spaces.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks. I didn't notice that `Last Updated: ` was part of the string. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

just try.

```
    NSString *currentString = @"recent update Last Updated: 10/02/2014 03:22:PM";

    NSString *tempoString = [currentString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 39)];

    NSArray* stringArray = [tempoString componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
    NSString* date = [stringArray objectAtIndex: 1];

    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: If you are going to hardcode a range, why not simply give the exact range of the needed text?